# Android swipe view one by one with title for group of view like IOS collection view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, uicollectionview, android-viewpager, horizontal-scrolling

[IOS collection view sample deisgn](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13X_Ao3zbYl2UkREDmpKq8sBLysbwFdmr/view?usp=sharing)
How can I achieve the same design in Android. Is it possible to do same UI in Recyclerview if yes can anyone guide me to do this?

I done it using ViewPager but I achieved partially as it only scroll page by page [Android Sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gRWNmVYgqs7yJi3tlNJU50ZvNN70BJ0K/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: you need to use a recyclerview with horizontal orientation

Comment: Yes I attached sample videos. kindly see the both IOS and Android videos. How the title (Top view) and hour view(bottom view) scroll at same time in single view in IOS?

Comment: I don't know, if it's an iOS-based question, put a tag of iOS in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I think its not IOS based question. I need to achieve same look and feel like IOS and I already tagged "uicollectionview". Thank you for your time.

Comment: @kartiraman have you found solution for this?